# Criar uma Pergunta pelo Stack Exchange App (Android)

Tags: suporte

Meu smartphone de smart não tem nada, mas impulsionado pelo *gamification*  do Winter Bash eu instalei o aplicativo da Stack Exchange pra criar uma pergunta que eu faria pelo site mesmo.

Teria sido uma feliz coincidência por causa do [On the Road](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/on-the-road) se eu tivesse encontrado um meio de criar uma nova pergunta pelo aplicativo, coisa que, pelo menos pela descrição do aplicativo na Play Store, o aplicativo permite fazer.

É possível **mesmo** postar alguma coisa que não seja um comentário ou uma resposta, já que esses eu encontrei como, pelo aplicativo?

Comment: No meu dá para criar perguntas, no botão "menu" do meu smartphone

Comment: Putz... Eu sempre esqueço que esse "botão" faz alguma coisa. >.< Se quiser oficializar uma resposta, eu a marcaria como aceita.

Comment: deixa ver o que respondem os moderadores, eu também não tenho a certeza se existe outra forma.

Comment: Eu não posso responder porque meu celular não é Android. E o do utluiz, se bem me lembro, nem smartphone é. @JorgeB. Acho que você deve sim postar uma resposta.

Comment: Respondido @bfavaretto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para poderes fazer uma pergunta na aplicação Android do Stack Exchange só tens ir ao menu<sup>1</sup> do teu smartphone e aparece-te a opção de fazer uma pergunta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>1 - Como se pode ver na imagem</sup>

Comment: *Roger that*, mas o meu menu é do outro lado :p

Comment: Também pode ser no meio :P

Comment: Ou não ter o botão físico, e ser na tela como o meu ;)

Answer (score 5):

Se você não tem o botão de menu (como é o meu caso), você pode clicar no `Q`, na página do *feed*, conforme imagem abaixo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O problema é que o smartphone medíocre que eu tenho no momento tem uma tela muito pequena e esse ícone não aparecia. Agora que você mencionou, eu virei o aparelho e daí apareceu.

Comment: Sem problemas. Alguns não veem o `Q`, alguns não veem o menu :P Pus essa resposta aqui para termos as duas soluções, o `Q` nem sempre é tão intuitivo também.

Comment: Podia ser um sinalzinho de `+`. Ou pelo menos alguma coisa que se parecesse mais com a letra `Q`

Comment: Isso parece o simbolo do `Whats App`